# How to make arrays of same size in Python

Tags: python, arrays, concatenation

I would like to know is there an "easy" way to create two matching arrays inserting some dummy missing value in both arrays so they remain same size and indexes that are the same in both arrays remain the same, so for example:

`["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]` and `["B", "C", "E"]`

Would be

`["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]` and `["N/A", "B", "C", "N/A", "E", "N/A"]`

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: There are no 'easy ways', there are algorithms that do stuff. Have you _tried_ writing such an algorithm to solve the problem? If yes, please show your code.

Comment: Helo ForceBru, maybe I miss-spoken, i have solved the problem: `a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,3,5]
c = []

for el in a:
    if el in b:
        c.append (el)
    else:
        c.append (0)
print (c)`

Comment: please don't post code in the comments, add it to the question instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One-liner in a list comprehension to do this:

```
array_1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
array_2 = {"B", "C", "E"}

array_3 = [x if x in array_2 else "N/A" for x in array_1]

print(array_3)
```

result:

```
['N/A', 'B', 'C', 'N/A', 'E', 'N/A']
```

Note that I converted `array_2` to a `set` for quicker lookup.

Answer (score 4):

```
array_1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"] 
array_2 = ["B", "C", "E"]

array_3 = array_1

for n,x in enumerate(array_3):

    if x not in array_2:

        array_3[n] = np.nan

print (array_3)
```

out:

```
[nan, 'B', 'C', nan, 'E', nan]
```