Why are my dimensions different when using OpenAi embeddings in Python?
I have a single Python function that I am using the embed JSON objects are different lengths.  The issue I am having is that, somehow, the dimensions are different when comparing the vectors and I have no idea why.  First, here is my embedding function:
def get_embeddings(json_object: json) -> list:
    json_splitter = RecursiveJsonSplitter(max_chunk_size=2000)
    json_docs = json_splitter.split_json(json_object, True)
    embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(model="text-embedding-3-large", dimensions=3072)
    total_embeddings = []
    for json_doc in json_docs:
        vector_results = embeddings.embed_query(json.dumps(json_doc))
        if vector_results is not None:
            for vector in vector_results:
                total_embeddings.append(vector)
    return total_embeddings

I then save those embeddings in a JSON object with a call such as
json_object["embeddings'] = get_embeddings(input_json)

I wrote a similarity method using numpy that is as follows:
def get_similarity_score(vector_set1, vector_set2) -> float:
    # Convert the vector sets to numpy arrays
    vector_set1 = np.array(vector_set1)
    vector_set2 = np.array(vector_set2)

    # Calculate the cosine similarity between the two vector sets
    dot_product = np.dot(vector_set1, vector_set2)
    norm1 = np.linalg.norm(vector_set1)
    norm2 = np.linalg.norm(vector_set2)
    similarity_score = dot_product / (norm1 * norm2)

    # Map the similarity score to a range of 0 to 10
    similarity_score = (similarity_score + 1) * 5

    # Round the similarity score to two decimal places
    similarity_score = round(similarity_score, 2)

    return similarity_score

I call that method through a call such as
this_score = get_similarity_score(json_object1["embeddings"], json_object2["embeddings"])

This is giving me the error:
ValueError: shapes (30720,) and (21504,) not aligned: 30720 (dim 0) != 21504 (dim 0)

My JSON objects are long and complex so I tried just creating my own JSON that was simpler but followed the pattern list[dict[str, dict]].  That did not work.
I have tried using vector stores such as ChromaDB and Weaviate but the problem persists.
I am fairly sure I am screwing up the embedding somehow which is resulting in the dimension variance but I have no clue how to fix it.
Does anybody have any ideas?
Thank you!
Here is a link to a list of Topics: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6bcsu1t10o8zj1f8mz4y5/Topics.txt?rlkey=xfznwo7pwtrwixcs2cnwcqx1b&st=hwvhptnq&dl=0
I run each of those first through the embedding and then the get_similiarity functions.
I tried np.reshape but got an error that the array cannot be resized.  This article - Cannot reshape array of size into shape - explains that error and why reshape is not an option.
I think that my array of vectors in get_embeddings is causing the issue which means I need to somehow force that into a uniform array.
Any ideas?  and THANK YOU!

Where's the error? (full rraceback?).  Sounds like a np.dot with two 1d arrays.  Review the size (length) of those arrays - before you get to the error line. (before calling get_similarity_score)

Without the json inputs (samples?) we can't do much to debug the get_embeddings code.

Gotcha - I can never upload files here so I am not sure how to get the JSON to you.  The last time I added in a full stack trace I got yelled at by some commenters so I was afraid to do so again.  I will work to get both added to the question.  I am currently running a test using the numpy reshape option to see if that helps.

I just updated with the file for testing.  Thank you all for your help!  I have been stuck on this for weeks now.

While occasionally a full traceback is excessively long, I don't expect that to be the case here.  If my guess is right it will just show which line in get_similarity is raising the error.  We need that at least.

reshape can't change the total number of elements in an array.  It just changes the shape, e.g.  (4,) to (2,2) or (4,1), etc.  You could slice (index) the longer  (30720,) to match the shorter, but that means throwing out lots of values.  But we don't know if the size difference is due to how you extract the data, or if there is a real difference in the data between the two sources.  If necessary construct a sample JSON, wth known data, and verify the get_embeddings for correctness.

Basically based on your knowledge of a input_json, you need to determine whether the length  of get_embeddings(input_json) list is correct.  I'd also verify that some of the data (numbers?) is correct.

My challenge is that I am using an LLM to dynamically generate Topics based on a series of dynamic inputs.  To that end, I have no idea what the max dimensions will be so I will need to select some predetermined value and intelligently downsize arrays that are too large and upsize - without distorting the vector - those arrays that are too small.  I found this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41828741/how-to-make-arrays-of-same-size-in-python - that seems close but I think it distorts the vector.

As it turns out the answer was very easy - I just used NUMPY resize.  First I created all of the embeddings then I went through and found the average size and used resize to make all of the embeddings that size.
Problem solved!
